# A name for a specific type of transformation that takes a continuous function and outputs a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

I am looking for references on transformations of continuous functions to holomorphic functions using integrals as seen in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818228/gamelin-chapter-2-problem-ii-14-integral-of-complex-function-is-continuous) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179088/showing-a-function-defined-from-an-integral-is-entire)